# Baccarat game simulation

Tags: java, simulation, probability, combinatorics

I've written some code to enumerate all of the possible hands in a game of baccarat.  The problem is that the results differ from the results in two separate places online, which also agree with each other.

**Here are the answers found online:**

Banker wins    0.458597
Player wins    0.446247
Tie            0.095156

[wizard of odds](http://wizardofodds.com/games/baccarat/basics/#toc-Odds) 
reviewpokerrooms.com/casino-games/baccarat/odds-calculator.html

**A log of the enumBaccarat() function can be found [here](http://www.filedropper.com/log_14).**

**Here are the results from the enumBaccarat() function:**

SCORE p:48074, b:44955 t:10382
Prob p:0.44770758239239270625523092341969085952235129960809599898180311840, b:0.45959536930024790930245539965226079881547710295342223860381081920 t:0.09539546930852567198933768141898732254664847334297019797573259680

**Here are the results for 1 billion hands from the random() function:**

tie: 94258105, banker: 458337837, player: 447404058

tie: 0.094258105,
banker: 0.458337837, 
player: 0.447404058

**Here is the important class:**

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

import org.apache.commons.math3.util.CombinatoricsUtils;

public class BaccaratGame 
{
    
    private Vector<Integer> player = new Vector<Integer>(0);
    private Vector<Integer> banker = new Vector<Integer>(0);
    private int playerTotal;
    private int bankerTotal;
    private BaccaratShoe shoe;
    private int playerWin = 0;
    private int bankerWin = 0;
    private int tie = 0;
    
    private BigDecimal playerProb = new BigDecimal(0);
    private BigDecimal bankerProb = new BigDecimal(0);
    private BigDecimal tieProb = new BigDecimal(0);
    
    public BaccaratGame(BaccaratShoe shoe)
    {
        this.shoe = shoe;
        this.bankerWin=0;
        this.playerWin=0;
        this.tie=0;
    }
    //Player chooses bets
    //action happens
    
    //two cards delt
    private int getBankerTotal()
    {
        bankerTotal = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < banker.size(); i++)
        {
            bankerTotal += banker.get(i);
        }
        bankerTotal = bankerTotal % 10;
        return bankerTotal;
    }
    
    private int getPlayerTotal()
    {
        playerTotal = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < player.size(); i++)
        {
            playerTotal += player.get(i);
        }
        playerTotal = playerTotal % 10;
        return playerTotal;
    }
    public void reseed()
    {
        //shoe.replaceCards(player);
        //shoe.replaceCards(banker);
        player = new Vector<Integer>(0);
        banker = new Vector<Integer>(0);
        getPlayerTotal();
        getBankerTotal();       
    }
    public int oneRandomHand()
    {
        BaccaratShoe tmp = shoe;
        player.add(tmp.dealRandomCard().getValue());
        player.add(tmp.dealRandomCard().getValue());
        
        banker.add(tmp.dealRandomCard().getValue());
        banker.add(tmp.dealRandomCard().getValue());
        
        
        getBankerTotal();
        getPlayerTotal();
        
        if(playerTotal < 8 && bankerTotal < 8)
        {
            if(playerTotal < 6)
            {
                //player draws third card
                BaccaratCard third = tmp.dealRandomCard();
                player.add(third.getValue());
                getPlayerTotal();
                //weird banker rules
                if(third.getValue() < 4)
                {
                    if(bankerTotal < 5)
                    {
                        //banker draws third card
                        banker.add(tmp.dealRandomCard().getValue());
                        getBankerTotal();
                        
                    }
                }
                else if(third.getValue() < 6)
                {
                    if(bankerTotal < 6)
                    {
                        //banker draws third card
                        banker.add(tmp.dealRandomCard().getValue());
                        getBankerTotal();
                        
                    }
                }
                else if(third.getValue() < 8)
                {
                    if(bankerTotal < 7)
                    {
                        //banker draws third card
                        banker.add(tmp.dealRandomCard().getValue());
                        getBankerTotal();
                        
                    }
                }
                else if(third.getValue() == 8)
                {
                    if(bankerTotal < 3)
                    {
                        //banker draws third card
                        banker.add(tmp.dealRandomCard().getValue());
                        getBankerTotal();
                        
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //A9T
                    if(bankerTotal < 4)
                    {
                        //banker draws third card
                        banker.add(tmp.dealRandomCard().getValue());
                        getBankerTotal();       
                    }
                }       
            }
            else if(bankerTotal < 6)
            {
                //banker draws third card
                banker.add(tmp.dealRandomCard().getValue());
                getBankerTotal();
            }
        }
        return getWinner();
            
    }
    
    public void recordWinner(Vector<Integer> originalRanks)
    {
        int winner = getWinner();
        BigDecimal prob = getProb(originalRanks, player, banker);
        
        if(winner==-1)
        {
            this.bankerProb = this.bankerProb.add(prob);
            this.bankerWin++;
        }
        else if(winner==1)
        {
            this.playerProb = this.playerProb.add(prob);
            this.playerWin++;
        }
        else if(winner==0)
        {
            this.tieProb = this.tieProb.add(prob);
            this.tie++;
        }
        String playerHand = "p: ";
        for(int i=0; i < player.size(); i++)
        {
            playerHand += player.get(i).toString() + " ";
        }
        String bankerHand = "b: ";
        for(int i=0; i < banker.size(); i++)
        {
            bankerHand += banker.get(i).toString() + " ";
        }
        System.out.println("HAND " + playerHand + bankerHand);
        System.out.println("SCORE p:" + String.valueOf(this.playerWin) + ", b:" + String.valueOf(this.bankerWin) + " t:" + String.valueOf(this.tie));
        System.out.println("Prob p:" + this.playerProb.toString() + ", b:" + this.bankerProb.toString() + " t:" + this.tieProb.toString());
        System.out.println("current prob=" + prob.toString());

    }
    public int getWinner()
    {
        getBankerTotal();
        getPlayerTotal();
        if(bankerTotal == playerTotal)
        {
            return 0; // tie
        }
        else if(bankerTotal > playerTotal)
        {
            return -1; // banker wins
        } 
        else
        {
            return 1; // player wins
        }
        
    }
    public boolean dragon7Winner()
    {
        if(banker.size() != 3)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(getBankerTotal() != 7)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(getWinner() != -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;    
    }
    public boolean panda8Winner()
    {
        if(player.size() != 3)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(getPlayerTotal() != 8)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(getWinner() != 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;    
    }
    public BigDecimal getProb(Vector<Integer> ranks, Vector<Integer> player, Vector<Integer> banker)
    {
        //count of the ranks before the hands are dealt
        
        //check for pairs
        
        //get a total of ranks
        int totalCards = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < ranks.size(); i++)
        {
            totalCards += ranks.get(i);
        }
        String rankStr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            rankStr+= i + "[" + ranks.get(i) + "] ";
        }
        System.out.println(rankStr);
        int card1Count = ranks.get(player.get(0));
        int card2Count = ranks.get(player.get(1));

        BigDecimal current = getHandPercentge(card1Count, card2Count, totalCards, 2); 
        //System.out.println("c1:" + current.toString());
        if(player.get(0) == player.get(1))
        {
            current = getHandPercentge(card1Count, card2Count - 1, totalCards, 2).divide(new BigDecimal(2));
        }
        else
        {
            current = getHandPercentge(card1Count, card2Count, totalCards, 2);
        }
        totalCards = totalCards - 2;getClass();
        
        if(player.size() > 2)
        {
            int card3Count = ranks.get(player.get(2));
            if(player.get(2) == player.get(1))
            {
                card3Count = card3Count - 1;
            }
            if(player.get(2) == player.get(0))
            {
                card3Count = card3Count - 1;
            }   
            current = current.multiply(new BigDecimal(card3Count).divide(new BigDecimal(totalCards), 16, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
        }
        totalCards = totalCards - 1;
        
        card1Count = ranks.get(banker.get(0));
        card2Count = ranks.get(banker.get(1));
        
        for(int i = 0; i < player.size(); i++)
        {
            if(player.get(i) == banker.get(0))
            {
                card1Count = card1Count - 1;
            }
            if(player.get(i) == banker.get(1))
            {
                card2Count = card2Count - 1;
            }
        }
        if(banker.get(0) == banker.get(1))
        {
            current = current.multiply(getHandPercentge(card1Count, card2Count - 1, totalCards, 2).divide(new BigDecimal(2)));
        }
        else
        {
            current = current.multiply(getHandPercentge(card1Count, card2Count, totalCards, 2));
        }
        
        totalCards = totalCards - 2;
        if(banker.size() > 2)
        {
            int card3Count = ranks.get(banker.get(2));
            if(banker.get(2) == player.get(1))
            {
                card3Count = card3Count - 1;
            }
            if(banker.get(2) == player.get(0))
            {
                card3Count = card3Count - 1;
            }
            if(player.size() > 2)
            {
                if(banker.get(2) == player.get(2))
                {
                    card3Count = card3Count - 1;
                }   
            }
            if(banker.get(2) == banker.get(1))
            {
                card3Count = card3Count - 1;
            }
            if(banker.get(2) == banker.get(0))
            {
                card3Count = card3Count - 1;
            }
            //System.out.println("card3Count=" + card3Count);
            current = current.multiply(new BigDecimal(card3Count).divide(new BigDecimal(totalCards), 16, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
            
        }
        //System.out.println("last:" + current.toString());
        return current;
    }
    public static BigDecimal getHandPercentge(int card1Count, int card2Count, int totalCards, int numberToDraw)
    {
        return new BigDecimal(card1Count).multiply(new BigDecimal(card2Count).divide(new BigDecimal(CombinatoricsUtils.binomialCoefficient(totalCards, numberToDraw)), 16 ,RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    }
    public void enumBaccarat()
    {
        Vector<Integer> ranks = new Vector<Integer>(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ranks.add(i, 0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < shoe.getSize(); i++)
        {
            int index = shoe.getCard(i).getValue();
            int current = ranks.get(index);
            ranks.set(index, current + 1);
        }
        Vector<Integer> originalRanks = new Vector<Integer>(0);
        originalRanks.addAll(ranks);
        String rankStr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            rankStr+= i + "[" + ranks.get(i) + "] ";
        }
        System.out.println(rankStr);
        for (int one = 0; one < 10; one++)
        {
            Vector<Integer> tmpRanks = ranks;
            int current = tmpRanks.get(one);
            if(current <= 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            player.add(0, one);
            tmpRanks.set(one, current - 1);
            //deal first 4 cards
            //check if more should be dealt
            for (int two = 0; two < 10; two++)
            {
                
                current = tmpRanks.get(two);
                if(current <= 0)
                {
                    continue;//skip cards we've run out of
                }
                banker.add(0, two);
                tmpRanks.set(two, current - 1);
                for (int three = 0; three <= one; three++)
                {
                    
                    current = tmpRanks.get(three);
                    if(current <= 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    player.add(1, three);
                    tmpRanks.set(three, current - 1);
                    for (int four = 0; four <= two; four++)
                    {
                    
                        
                        current = tmpRanks.get(four);
                        if(current <= 0)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        banker.add(1, four);
                        tmpRanks.set(four, current - 1);
                        
                        if(getPlayerTotal() < 8 && getBankerTotal() < 8)
                        {
                            if(getPlayerTotal() < 6)
                            {
                                //player draws 3rd card
                                for(int five = 0; five < 10; five++)
                                {   
                                    current = tmpRanks.get(five);
                                    if(current <= 0)
                                    {
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    player.add(2, five);
                                    tmpRanks.set(five, current - 1);
                                    int tmpBT = getBankerTotal();
                                    if(tmpBT == 7)
                                    {
                                        recordWinner(originalRanks);

                                        rankStr = "";
                                        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                                        {
                                            rankStr+= i + "[" + ranks.get(i) + "] ";
                                        }
                                        System.out.println(rankStr);
                                    }
                                    else if(tmpBT < 3)
                                    {
                                        for(int six = 0; six < 10; six++)
                                        {
                                            current = tmpRanks.get(six);
                                            if(current <= 0)
                                            {
                                                continue;
                                            }
                                            banker.add(2, six);
                                            recordWinner(originalRanks);
                                            
                                            rankStr = "";
                                            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                                            {
                                                rankStr+= i + "[" + ranks.get(i) + "] ";
                                            }
                                            System.out.println(rankStr);
                                            banker.remove(2);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if(tmpBT == 6)
                                    {
                                        if(five==6 || five==7)  
                                        {
                                            for(int six = 0; six < 10; six++)
                                            {
                                                current = tmpRanks.get(six);
                                                if(current <= 0)
                                                {
                                                    continue;
                                                }
                                                banker.add(2, six);
                                                recordWinner(originalRanks);
                                                
                                                rankStr = "";
                                                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                                                {
                                                    rankStr+= i + "[" + ranks.get(i) + "] ";
                                                }
                                                System.out.println(rankStr);
                                                banker.remove(2);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            recordWinner(originalRanks);
                                            
                                            rankStr = "";
                                            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                                            {
                                                rankStr+= i + "[" + ranks.get(i) + "] ";
                                            }
                                            System.out.println(rankStr);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if(tmpBT == 5)
                                    {
                                        if(five > 3 && five < 8)    
                                        {
                                            for(int six = 0; six < 10; six++)
                                            {
                                                current = tmpRanks.get(six);
                                                if(current <= 0)
                                                {
                                                    continue;
                                                }
                                                banker.add(2, six);
                                                recordWinner(originalRanks);
                                                
                                                rankStr = "";
                                                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                                                {
                                                    rankStr+= i + "[" + ranks.get(i) + "] ";
                                                }
                                                System.out.println(rankStr);
                                                banker.remove(2);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            recordWinner(originalRanks);
                                            
                                            rankStr = "";
                                            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                                            {
                                                rankStr+= i + "[" + ranks.get(i) + "] ";
                                            }
                                            System.out.println(rankStr);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if(tmpBT == 4)
                                    {
                                        if(five > 1 && five < 8)    
                                        {
                                            for(int six = 0; six < 10; six++)
                                            {
                                                current = tmpRanks.get(six);
                                                if(current <= 0)
                                                {
                                                    continue;
                                                }
                                                banker.add(2, six);
                                                recordWinner(originalRanks);
                                                
                                                rankStr = "";
                                                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                                                {
                                                    rankStr+= i + "[" + ranks.get(i) + "] ";
                                                }
                                                System.out.println(rankStr);
                                                banker.remove(2);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            recordWinner(originalRanks);
                                            
                                            rankStr = "";
                                            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                                            {
                                                rankStr+= i + "[" + ranks.get(i) + "] ";
                                            }
                                            System.out.println(rankStr);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if(tmpBT == 3)
                                    {
                                        if(five != 8)   
                                        {
                                            for(int six = 0; six < 10; six++)
                                            {
                                                current = tmpRanks.get(six);
                                                if(current <= 0)
                                                {
                                                    continue;
                                                }
                                                banker.add(2, six);
                                                recordWinner(originalRanks);
                                                
                                                rankStr = "";
                                                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                                                {
                                                    rankStr+= i + "[" + ranks.get(i) + "] ";
                                                }
                                                System.out.println(rankStr);
                                                banker.remove(2);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            recordWinner(originalRanks);
                                            
                                            rankStr = "";
                                            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                                            {
                                                rankStr+= i + "[" + ranks.get(i) + "] ";
                                            }
                                            System.out.println(rankStr);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    player.remove(2);
                                    tmpRanks.set(five, tmpRanks.get(five) + 1);
                                }
                                
                            }
                            else if(getBankerTotal() < 6)
                            {
                                for(int five = 0; five < 10; five++)
                                {
                                    current = tmpRanks.get(five);
                                    if(current <= 0)
                                    {
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    banker.add(2, five);
                                    recordWinner(originalRanks);
                                    
                                    rankStr = "";
                                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                                    {
                                        rankStr+= i + "[" + ranks.get(i) + "] ";
                                    }
                                    System.out.println(rankStr);
                                    banker.remove(2);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                recordWinner(originalRanks);
                                
                                rankStr = "";
                                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                                {
                                    rankStr+= i + "[" + ranks.get(i) + "] ";
                                }
                                System.out.println(rankStr);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            recordWinner(originalRanks);
                            
                            rankStr = "";
                            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                            {
                                rankStr+= i + "[" + ranks.get(i) + "] ";
                            }
                            System.out.println(rankStr);
                        }

                        banker.remove(1);
                        tmpRanks.set(four, tmpRanks.get(four) + 1);
                    }
                    player.remove(1);
                    tmpRanks.set(three, tmpRanks.get(three) + 1);
                }
                banker.remove(0);
                tmpRanks.set(two, tmpRanks.get(two) + 1);
            }   
            player.remove(0);
            tmpRanks.set(one, tmpRanks.get(one) + 1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider another example, a single roll of a fair die.  Theoretically, the probabilities are:

1. 1/6
2. 1/6
3. 1/6
4. 1/6
5. 1/6
6. 1/6

But if you did a simulation, you would most likely wind up with probabilites that are all a little different than 1/6.

So if your baccarat simulation results seem a little different than the theoretical ones, don't be all that surprised.

However, in this particular example, it seems that your code behaves differently that the Wizard Of Odds results you're trying to compare to, e.g. in the case where `third.getValue() < 4`. Be sure your simulation matches what you're trying to compare it to in all details, including the rules and number of decks. Once some cards have been dealt from the deck, the probability of the next card having any particular value is slightly different than it would be if different-valued cards were already dealt.

Comment: In one of the functions I test every possible combination.  I did both a simulation and an enumeration, and they both disagree with the published results.  In one of the functions I test every possible combination

Comment: Are you sure you're following the exact same rules as the Wizard of Odds numbers you're comparing to?  Do you get the same intermediate results?

Comment: As sure as I can be,  I've triple checked the logic to see if I can find any differences, which I cannot.  I don't understand what you mean by  intermediate results.

Comment: For example, modify your code to reproduce the hit/stand table.  I think you should especially look at what happens when `third.getValue() < 4`.

Comment: Your advice was good.  I completely rewrote the code from the ground up doing more rigorous testing of each function as it was written.  I have now duplicated the results from the other sources.

Comment: @stodosisis Great, glad it was helpful.